# 8 byte Integer with Doctrine and PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, floating-point, doctrine, integer

the players:

1. 64bit linux with
2. php 5 (ZendFramework 1.10.2)
3. PostgreSQL 8.3
4. Doctrine 1.2

Via a Flash/Flex client i get an 8byte integer value.
the field in the database is an BIGINT (8 byte)

PHP_INT_SIZE show that system supports 8byte integer.

printing out the value in the code as it is and as intval() leads to this:

```
Plain:  1269452776100  
intval: 1269452776099
```

float rounding failure ?

but what really driving me nuts is

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1269452776099.000000"'

when i try to use it in a query. like:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('table')->findBy('external_id',$external_id);
```

or

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('table')->findBy('external_id',intval($external_id));
```

How i am supposed to handle this ? or how can i give doctrine a floating point number which it should use on a bigint field ?

Any help is much appreciated!
TIA

EDIT:

from the model:

```
    $this->hasColumn('external_id', 'integer', 8, array(
     'type' => 'integer',
     'length' => 8,
     'fixed' => false,
     'unsigned' => false,
     'notnull' => false,
     'primary' => false,
     ));
```

Database field is bigint 8 bytes.

EDIT2:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48924 seems to be the root of the problem

Comment: Did you build rou model from the DB, from a yaml schema, or did you create it manually? It sounds like there is a descrepency between your model definition of the column and its actual type.

Comment: yaml is build from DB, models are build from yaml. model definition and DB are correct.

Comment: PostgreSQL 7.3? Are you sure? Send it to a museum, that's where it belongs. No support, no updates, no security. Or did you mean version 8.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already mentioned, you hit [**this bug**](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48924).

To work around it, pass the parameter as a string and make sure it's converted to a `BIGINT` on the database side:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create();
$q->from('table AS t')
  ->where("t.external_id = CAST(:external_id AS BIGINT)", array(':external_id'  => $external_id))
  ->limit(1);
$result = $q->execute();
```